# Term for Irregular Verb

Tags: terminology

Good day everyone!

I browsed the internet and couldn't find a word to describe irregular verbs in German.

1. Verb -> Verb
2. Noun -> Substantiv
3. Adjective -> Adjektiv
4. Irregular Verb -> ???

Is there a word for "irregular verb" in German? What I mean by irregular is for verbs like **lesen**, when it meets **du**, it changes into **liest** (not **lesst**) as **sitzen** into **sitz** (not **sitzst**) and **essen** into **isst** (not **essst**). Looking forward for the answers, thank you very much! :)

Comment: The term you are looking for is _unregelmässiges Verb_, the direct translation from the English words.

Comment: The term *Nomen* for noun is also common.

Comment: @Janka Yes, the term is common, but - in my opinion - as a synonym for "Substantiv" ("nomen substantivum") infuriatingly incorrect.

Comment: https://dict.leo.org/german-english/irregular%20verb, also vote to close

Comment: @problemofficer, why voted to close this question? It's a question about terminology, not a direct translation of a word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term for *irregular Verb* is **unregelmässiges Verb**, but you aren't looking for these. German verbs follow one of four patterns.

- schwache Beugung *(weak conjugation)*
- starke Beugung *(strong conjugation)*
- gemischte Beugung *(mixed conjugation)*
- unregelmäßige Beugung *(irregular conjugation)*

Your examples *lesen*, *sitzen* and *essen* follow the *strong conjugation* pattern. They have an **Ablaut**, a vowel change in the stem. Please learn about the strong and mixed conjugation patterns from your grammar book.

In German, only very few verbs are truly irregular, **sein** for example, and some verbs which have two different past participles.

Comment: Ah, I see. I haven't learned those patterns yet. I am learning from a book and **it gives examples in complex German sentences**, which is why I decided to improve my vocabularies first and asked this question to keep my study on track.

Comment: It's okay to focus on vocabulary first. Those grammar terms aren't too helpful in learning about German verbs, but you asked for the correct terminology.